# delete Polyline rendered with react-native(0.45.1), react-native-maps(0.15.3) and mapbox

Tags: react-native, mapbox, polyline, google-directions-api, react-native-maps

I need to delete the polyline I've drawn on the  component when a user performs a new search. Right now I end up with 2+ routes all drawn on the same map instead of the new search displaying only the new route.

I followed this tutorial to render the polyline: https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/react-native-maps-with-google-directions-api-bc716ed7a366.

I've tried emptying state(which gives the polyline the coordinates to draw through) in componentWillUnmount and ComponentWillMount.
I've also seen references to polyline.remove() but that functionality doesn't exists with react-native-maps or the mapbox/polyline package as far as I can tell. Mapbox appears to have a way to delete layers however I can't find a way to incorporate that into my project.

I'd appreciate any leads about how to delete the polyline.

Here's some of the code. JSX:

```
    <MapView style={styles.map} initialRegion={{
      latitude:startLat,
      longitude:startLng,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421
    }}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    loadingEnabled={true}
    loadingIndicatorColor="#e6fef6"
    loadingBackgroundColor="#400230"
    >
    <MapView.Polyline
        coordinates={this.state.coords}
        strokeWidth={2}
        strokeColor="purple"/>

    </MapView>
```

Decoding the Polyline:

```
      async getBikeDirections(startBike, endBike) {
try {
  let respBike = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${startBike}&destination=${endBike}&mode=bicycling`)

  let respJsonBike = await respBike.json()
  let completeBikeSteps = respJsonBike.routes[0].legs[0].steps
  let pointsBike = Polyline.decode(respJsonBike.routes[0].overview_polyline.points)

  let coordsBike = pointsBike.map((point, index) => {
    return {
      latitude: point[0],
      longitude: point[1]
    }
  })

  let text = completeBikeSteps.map((obj, index) => {
    let regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig,
      result = obj.html_instructions.replace(regex, "")
    return result
  })

  return {
    coordsBike,
    text
  }
} catch (error) {
  alert(error)
  return error
}
```

}